# blocks threaded freeze when the UIView moves

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, objective-c-blocks, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

All is title :)
I have this method :

```
[[NetworkManager sharedInstance] getContentFromUrl:url withId:@"json" onResultBlock:^(NSData *data, NSString *identifier) {
            NSLog(@"done")
    } onFailureBlock:^(NSError *error, NSString *identifier) {
        NSLog(@"error");
    }];
```

And in my app, i have one tableview with 50 cells.
When i run my app and that i move the tableview with my finger, the "done" message not appears. So, the next download does not start :(
But when i release my finger on the tableview, the "done" message appear...

information:
The method getContentFromUrl instanciates an object that is subclassed by NSOperation. In this object, i fetch the content with NSURLConnection initWithRequest:delegate:
Then, the object is add in NSOperationQueue.

Thx for answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `NetworkManager` class is scheduling asynchronous `NSURLConnection` objects on the main thread in the default run loop mode. While your finger is down, the run loop is put into the `NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode` mode instead. This will pause the connection.

`NetworkManager` should be modified to schedule the connection explicitly using `NSRunLoopCommonModes`. This includes the default mode and the event-tracking mode.

Comment: I didn't know ... Just another question, if i use NSURLConnection with sendSynchronousRequest, i would the same problem ? Another thing, i use concurrency thread. Thx you very much for help.

Comment: In fact, i would like to know, in the cases where i have a tableview, if i will can to add and display the images to download from network on this tableview during the scrolling for exemple.

Comment: @marcL: Do not use `sendSynchronousRequest`. Even on a background thread. That will tie up an entire OS thread for no good reason. Using an asynchronous request scheduled on the runloop with `NSRunLoopCommonModes` is sufficient. And yes, you can display the images during scrolling. If you're scheduled in `NSRunLoopCommonModes`, you can get the image and then stick it in the cell. If you're on a background thread, just make sure to use `-performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:modes:` and pass `NSRunLoopCommonModes` as the mode.